# Inputting logical constraints into a binary programming model in Gurobi

Tags: integer-programming, python, gurobi, logical-constraints

I am very new to Gurobi and OR in general (I'm in my first class for it now), so apologies if this is a very obvious answer. For a project in that class, I am generating a flight schedule for a theoretical airline. I am attempting to add a logical constraint relating to flow balance across cities for crew members, which basically says if expression A is true, then expression B must be true. I was attempting to use the `model.addGenConstrIndicator` function, but it will not allow me to input an expression for the "if" part of the function, only a single binary variable.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce two binary variables, say $x_A$ and $x_B$, two indicator constraints $x_A \iff A$ and $x_B \iff B$, and linear constraint $x_A \le x_B$.  The latter enforces the implication $x_A \implies x_B$, which is equivalent to $A \implies B$.